# Stopping img:hover transform from scaling outside its box

Tags: html, css

On hover, the scale transform starts to overlap the other pictures in it's row. I'm not sure how to prevent this and just have the scale stay within it's own picture.

**HTML**

```
<div id="pictures">
    <img src="/pic1.jpg"/>
    <img src="/pic2.jpg"/>
    <img src="/pic3.jpeg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pictures {
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#pictures img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
}

#pictures:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

#pictures img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .9s ease-in-out;
    transition: .9s ease-in-out;
}

#pictures img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: Wrap each image in it's own div and apply `overflow:hidden` to the wrapping div.

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh so I can't do it like a few at a time as above? I ask because there will really be like 40 pictures or something. I figured there's an easier way than putting a div around each individual picture.

Comment: Depends how you are writing code. If it's PHP then it's an `include` issue. If you're putting them in by hand it's a lot harder. A `transform` is just that...it make elements bigger. That's what you told it to do...so it is.

Comment: It's all HTML/CSS. Guess I'll get to adding div's in each one then. Thanks!